# Не могу передать данные из одного класса в SQL запрос другого

Tags: java, sql

Делаю запрос к БД:

```
String query = "select * from users where name = '"+ login +"\'";
```

класс видит переменную `login` как `Null`

`Login` добываю из другого класса способом:

```
login = yourLogin.getText();
```

В нем логин видится корректно.

Необходимо ли мне каким то образом сохранять полученные `getText()` данные в файл, перед тем как запрашивать их у БД? Или я неверно передаю данные из одного класса в другой.

Comment: Покажите лучше код и того и другого класса и моменты где  и как все передается

Answer (score 2):

Передай в метод `connection` к БД и `login`:

```
void execSQL(Connection con, String login) throws SQLException {
    final String strSQL = "select * from users where name = ?"; 
    if (con != null && login != null) {
        try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(strSQL)) {
            pstm.setObject(1, login);
            try (ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    String name = rs.getString("NAME");
                    System.out.println(name); 
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("login  или  коннект null");
    }
}
```